# Creating a projectile trajectory in Allegro

Tags: c, allegro, allegro5

I'm developing a 2D game in C using Allegro 5, where an enemy from a fixed position shoots a projectile at the player's current position. I know I will have to calculate the tangent of an imaginary triangle based on the player's position and the enemy's. However, how can I have the projectile follow a straight line based on that value?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: I'm not so sure as to how I can code angles, so I haven't had much success.

Comment: So no gravity ?

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you're asking, but the projectile is supposed to go in a straight trajectory, from point a (enemy character) to b (player character), without any external influences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a situation where can be easier to work with vectors than angles.

Some simple math computes the vector between the enemy and the player:

```
# Compute the x and y displacement from the enemy to the player
dx = player_x - enemy_x
dy = player_y - enemy_y

# normalize the displacement to get the direction vector 
distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
projectile.dir_x = dx / distance
```

```

The projectile just needs to follow that vector during the update loop:

```
projectile.x += projectile.dir_x * projectile.speed * time_elapsed
projectile.y += projectile.dir_y * projectile.speed * time_elapsed
```